# Systemd killed my vetcore service: "Deactivated succesfully"

Tags: systemd, services

So I created a systemd file for my netcore bash script on Linux. But when I start the service file, `systemd` keep killing it with the result "service: Deactivated successfully."

I tried to insert `Type=forking` or `Type=oneshot` but neither works. What should I do?

This is the service file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/updatem
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is the result :

```
10:57 AM    kill UpdateM
10:57 AM    starting UpdateM
10:57 AM    3
10:57 AM    2
10:57 AM    1
10:57 AM    UpdateM (v.1.0.0.12)
10:57 AM    UpdateM (v.1.0.0.12) UP.
10:57 AM    Start
10:57 AM    updatem.service: Deactivated successfully.
10:57 AM    Finished Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Type=oneshot`, you will often also want `RemainAfterExit=yes`, so that systemd will consider the service as "running" after the process invoked by the `ExecStart=` line has ended.

From `man systemd.service` regarding `Type=oneshot`:

> Note that if this option is used without `RemainAfterExit=` the service will never enter "active" unit state, but will directly transition from "activating" to "deactivating" or "dead", since no process is configured that shall run continuously. In particular this means that after a service of this type ran (and which has `RemainAfterExit=` not set) it will not show up as started afterwards, but as dead.

So the behavior you're seeing is exactly as expected with `Type=oneshot` + no `RemainAfterExit=yes`.

If your `/usr/bin/updatem` script actually creates a child process that is supposed to keep running, then `Type=forking` would be the correct choice of service type.

But if the `/usr/bin/updatem` script only sends a command to some other already existing process causing *it* to start something else, and the script and all its direct descendants will die off as soon as the command is sent, then `Type=oneshot`, probably with `RemainAfterExit=yes`, would be the right choice.

You could then also add a `ExecStop=` line pointing to another script that would send another command to stop the thing started by the `/usr/bin/updatem` script, if needed. That would allow `systemctl stop UpdateM.service` to also be a meaningful operation, and it would make systemd stop your thing more gracefully at system shutdown time, if it is still running.

If you modify the service file without using `systemctl edit`, remember that you'll need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to make the service file changes take effect.